# How to call a static function defined in a sealed class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop

I have a public class and it contains a static function as given below:-

```
public class demo1
{
    public static int GetFactorials(int number)
    {
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            result *= i;
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

How to call this static function `GetFactorials`?

Comment: Try `demo1.GetFactorials(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static function/method doesn't requires object.

```
demo1.GetFactorials(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple:

```
demo1.GetFactorials(123);
```